# Difference in memory used between declaring integer iterator inside and outside a nested for-loop

Tags: c++, memory-management, integer

Code 1:

```
int solution(vector<vector<int>>& arr){
    int ans, m = arr.size(), n = arr[0].size(); // it is given that m is atleast 1
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            // do something
            // i and j are only used for iterating over the array
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Code 2:

```
int solution(vector<vector<int>>& arr){
    int i, j, ans, m = arr.size(), n = arr[0].size();
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
            // do something
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

I thought code2 uses less memory since code1 declares variable `j` in the for loop `m` times (This is not true as mentioned in comments and answer). But I was doubtful when I saw many coders in online coding platforms preferring to use code1 over code2.

I appreciate any explanation about the difference in memory used for the two codes.

Comment: (1) is always better, unless you need the variables outside of the loop. Any sane compiler will compile them to the same thing.

Comment: They are identical. The memory used value is almost certainly just heap memory, and none of those variables affect it in any way.

Comment: @susanth29: This is a good starting point: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if. In summary, your source code is the *intention*. What the compiler actually produces is down to it.

Comment: Just explore the produced assembly yourself by using godbolt.org. It's a great online compiler to explore code snippets with.

Comment: There's a lot, a lot more to learn about C++ than these kinds of trivialities. There's a lot more about C++ [to be found in a good textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242) than on web sites that have nothing but lists of useless programming puzzles that nobody really cares about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Andreas Brunnet` suggested I tried compiling both codes in `godbolt.org` and as `HolyBlackCat` said the assembly code for both the codes is the same. Here's the code used and the corresponding assembly code (the compiler option is `x86-64 gcc 11.2`).

Code:

```
#include <vector>
int sum(std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr) {
    int i, j, ans = 0, m = arr.size(), n = arr[0].size(); // i, j deleted in code2
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++){ // int i = 0 in code2
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){ // int j = 0 in code2
            ans += arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

and the assembly code for both the codes is:

```
sum(std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 48
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-40], rdi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], 0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-40]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >::size() const
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-16], eax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-40]
        mov     esi, 0
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >::operator[](unsigned long)
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::size() const
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], eax
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
        jmp     .L2
.L5:
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 0
        jmp     .L3
.L4:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        movsx   rdx, eax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-40]
        mov     rsi, rdx
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >::operator[](unsigned long)
        mov     rdx, rax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        cdqe
        mov     rsi, rax
        mov     rdi, rdx
        call    std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::operator[](unsigned long)
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
        add     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], eax
        add     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 1
.L3:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        cmp     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
        jl      .L4
        add     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
.L2:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        cmp     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
        jl      .L5
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
        leave
        ret
```

and as I understand, lines 18,19,43,45,46,47 in assembly code correspond to line 5 of c++ code and lines 21,22,38,40,41,42 correspond to line 6 (Correct me if I am wrong). i.e.

```
18:        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
19:        jmp     .L2
43:        add     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
44:.L2:
45:        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
46:        cmp     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
47:        jl      .L5
```

is corresponding code of `for((int) i = 0; i < m; i++)` and

```
20:.L5:
21:        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 0
22:        jmp     .L3
38:        add     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 1
39:.L3:
40:        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
41:        cmp     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
42:        jl      .L4
```

correspond to `for((int) j = 0; j < n; j++)`

Clearly, the compiler assigns only one register for `j` in both codes. So, the memory used is the same.